# Misleading chat usercard on SE 2.0 chat

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation, badges, chat

[My SE 2.0 chat usercard](https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/31768/manishearth) (and everyone else's) is slightly misleading. Underneath my main account, it shows my Physics.SE badges and my *total* network rep. To me, it looks as if I have 13k rep on Phy.SE (w00t!)--which I don't.

[image]

Anyone think that it should be slightly clearer which is which?

Comment: I'd call this a bug, not a feature.. Either show total network rep *and* total badges counts, or take both numbers from just the parent.

Comment: Yep, this is very misleading

Comment: And 2 and a half years later, Manishearth's Physics reputation is approaching the total depicted in the screenshot. :-)

Answer (score 5):

The badges have now been revised to follow the same rules as reputation, which means that we look at all the sites for which you have at least 200 reputation (this is the rule that chat.SE has always used for aggregating reputation, to prevent artificial inflation just from visiting other sites and getting the rep bonus).

Comment: Presumably there is some caching going on still, as ManishEarth's chat account is still some 1300 badges short from their network total. But on my chat profile it looks correct at least.

Comment: @MartijnPieters user account refreshes are prompted by activity on the site; we don't update everyone in chat all the time. I have clicked the admin button to refresh that account; check now.

Comment: As always, the answer is caching. Looks great!

Comment: @MartijnPieters especially if the question is "how do you make a multi-user system performant, when the data is logically, physically and geographically separated, with no shared access between the disjoint systems, and high latency for indirect access. and each system must continue working even if the other is unavailable?" (as it is in this case ;p)

Comment: Of course, why have it easy? :-P

Comment: Thanks! @MartijnPieters whoa, I have a lot more badges than I thought I did ;P