# Apparently I have 10.1K on SO....I don't

Tags: support, chat, profile-page

[image]

Seem's to be something weird going on in chat??

https://chat.stackexchange.com/users/103069/liam

I actually have 5K. Am I missing something or is this a bug?

[image]

Comment: @Oded: the use of total network rep vs. parent-account badges *is* odd and confusing and probably a bug.

Comment: @MartijnPieters the badge thing has been changed today

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your network-wide *total* reputation is 10k:

[image: 10k rep]

All accounts with 200 points or more count; see your [Stack Exchange profile](https://stackexchange.com/users/259401/liam?tab=accounts).

A quick calculator check on your accounts there gets me 10068, closely matching the 10070 points the tooltip on your chat accounts gives you.

The https://chat.stackexchange.com chat server serves the whole network *except* Stack Overflow, so the total there reflects your participation across all sites. Stack Overflow is merely the first account you have and serves as the 'parent' account for the chat account.

What *is* odd is that the badge counts are not reflecting your network totals.

Comment: Seems odd. Why does it show the badges and icon for SO only but the rep for network wide? Seem's a little confusing to me?

Comment: @Liam: that is odd, and I found a duplicate report at [Misleading chat usercard on SE 2.0 chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/130078)

Comment: Yeah, feels wrong to me. I've +1'd the dupe. Feel free to mark as a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: @Liam and (waves magic wand) your [badges are now network wide](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/237948/23354)

Comment: Cheers @MarcGravell! Checked and it looks good

Comment: @MarcGravell: coolness!